# Nested Routing in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I have a very simple problem in my routing in ReactJS. I have a problem on my PrivateRoute. I cannot redirect to Customer or Product routes. Pls check my code below. Thanks.

**Routes.js**

```
function Routes() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Common} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default Routes;
```

**Common.js**

```
const Common = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <SideNav />
          <main className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Dashboard} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/customers" component={Customers} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/customers/:id" component={CustomersDetail} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/products" component={Products} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/products/:id" component={ProductsDetail} />
            </Switch>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default Common;
```

Comment: why u'r using switch in  common . you'r already used in route.js .

Comment: Please be more specific with what you are trying to achieve and what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendering nested routes you'll need to prepend the url path up to the nested routes.

[Route Nesting](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting)

***EDIT:*** meant to use `match.path` instead of `match.url`. `path` is the path pattern used to match and useful for building nested routes.

```
const Common = ({ match: { path } }) => { // extract the path from match route prop
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <SideNav />
        <main className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.toolbar} />
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute path={`${path}/customers/:id`} component={CustomersDetail} />
            <PrivateRoute path={`${path}/customers`} component={Customers} />
            <PrivateRoute path={`${path}/products/:id`} component={ProductsDetail} />
            <PrivateRoute path={`${path}/products`} component={Products} />
            <PrivateRoute path={[`${path}/`, `${path}/dashboard`]} component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

***NOTE:*** Reordered the routes a bit to match more specific paths first since `Switch` returns only the first match.

You'll need to also remove the `exact` prop from your root router so it can continue to match other sub-routes within `Common`.

```
function Routes() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Common} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: There's a problem when i redirect  to the products page, when i'm on the customer detail, it attached a relative route on it

Comment: I want the default route to appear like /dashboard, and when i i navigate to customers it should look like /customer

Comment: @Robert It can still access the `match` route prop and build a correct URL.

Comment: Why is there two urls in  <PrivateRoute path={[`${url}/`, `${url}/dashboard`]} component={Dashboard} />

Comment: @Robert They both render the same component, `Dashboard`. `path` can take a string or string[]. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string

Comment: Thanks. I edited your answers to like this ${url}customers/:id  instead of ${url}/customers/:id

Answer (score 0):

Remove the exact prop from

```
<PrivateRoute path="/" component={Common} />
```

Exact would only match '/'.  You'd want it to match all routes starting with /.
Also place the private route at the last after login and signup